# Passing AVPlayer to another ViewController no video but has sound

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

I'm trying to pass an AVPlayer to one tableviewcell to a different View Controller. I tested this on the simulator and it works but when I tested it in an iPhone, I can only hear the sound but no video. My purpose is to lessen loading time by using the same player and not the movie URL since I'm getting the video from the web and putting it on the AVPlayer.

VideoDetailsViewController.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) AVPlayer *player;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet VPVideoPlayer *videoPlayer;
```

VideoDetailsViewController.m

```
-(id)initWithAVPlayer:(AVPlayer*)player
{
if(self = [super initWithNibName:@"VideoDetailsViewController" bundle:nil]) {
_player = player;
}

return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];    
[self.videoPlayer setPlayer:self.player];
}
```

Parts of VideoPlayer.m

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if(self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {

    }

return self;
}

+ (Class)layerClass
{
    return [AVPlayerLayer class];
}

- (AVPlayer*)player
{
    return [(AVPlayerLayer*)[self layer] player];
}

- (void)setPlayer:(AVPlayer*)player
{
    [(AVPlayerLayer*)[self layer] setPlayer:player];
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Okay, here's a wild guess: could it be a timing problem? Does it work any better if you move `[self.videoPlayer setPlayer:self.player];` out of `viewDidLoad` and into, say, `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: Any solution updated? I have the same issue and no way can resolve.

Comment: @thynguyen248 Solved it maybe?

Comment: @RoiMulia Actually no. I just work around by not passing the AVPLayer but initializing the second VC beforehand and loading video the same time with the first VC. When presenting the second VC, I pass current playing time and use seekToTime. It seems as if the video is continuous played from the 1 AVPlayer. Such bad solution but this is the only way I have. Will try to research this and update if I can.

Comment: Got it, so You are initing the player at the second VC by overrating the init func? Or but calling vc.view and than trigger the whole life cycle?

Comment: @thynguyen248 See above :)

Comment: I initialize the second VC in first VC's viewDidLoad, then when I click play button in first VC and load the video, I also do the same thing in second VC (use AVURLAsset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys). For example in first VC tableViewCell’s click event, I will call [secondVC loadAsset:videoUrl];
And hold the video url in second VC as a property. So if you have many different video urls, when calling this loadAsset method again, check if this url is same with the url property so you don’t need to reload the video.